# Is the "resources" function in routes.rb only responsible for creating the URLs needed to access a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :users
    match '/signup',  to: 'users#new', via:'get'
end
```

In this tutorial, we have a `user` model. The author had us use `resources :users` to have rails generate the REST style URLs (/users, /users/new, etc). But then in the second line, he has us match `/signup` to `users#new`. If this line wasn't here, we would only be able to access users#new using the REST url generated with the `resources :users` line. In this case, it would be `/users/new`. But now, he has it setup so that if we want to access users#new, we just need to access `/signup`.

By matching `/signup` to `users#new`, are we technically completely neglecting the route that the `resources` function created for us? As far as I know, for users#new, the only thing `resources` did was route `/users/new` to `users#new`, but he isn't using that anymore. Is there something else that `resources` does, or is he completely throwing out the URL that it generated, and replacing it with `/signup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/signup` isn’t *replacing* `/users/new`, it’s complementing it. It’s common to create shortcuts for certain paths, especially for URLs that are more comprehensible to users.

Comment: But couldn't we get rid of `resources :users` and `/signup` would still work since all we need for `users#new` to exit is `def new` in the `users` controller?

Comment: Sure, if you don’t use any of the other methods on `UsersController`, `signup` would suffice. It’s true that all `resources :users` does is wire up the various `/users` paths to the controller and give you the `new_user_path`-type helpers.

Comment: So then, technically, `/signup` IS replacing just `/users/new`, yes?

Comment: Your use of “replacing” is unclear to me. It’s not removing `/users/new`, so to me, it’s not replacing it. But if you mean “removing the need for” when you say “replacing”, sure, that’s what’s happening.

Comment: Yes that is what i meant. The point I'm trying to make is that, if we created shortcuts (nicely named URLs, like `/signup`) for all the REST actions, then `resources :users` would not be needed, right? Assuming that we don't care for its helpers.

Comment: Yes, you wouldn’t need the `resources` line. You also get helpers for the `match`: `signup_path` and `signup_url`. But what shortcut for `users#create` really makes sense? It becomes increasingly cumbersome coming up with names to replace every controller action if you’re implementing them all.

Answer (score 1):

It won't get rid of the new route, it will simply map `/signup` to the `#new` action in addition to the normal new route.

Comment: but routing `/signup` to `users#new` implies that `/users/new` will never be used, but instead `/signup` will, right?